# Is it ok to use a gas stove with gas pressure lower than what's specified?

Tags: gas, stove

I got a new gas stove. I will use an LPG tank as the source for gas. The stove's user manual specifies to use gas at a pressure of 37mbar, and that "the company isn't responsible for any difference in performance or any risk if it is used at a different value". It also warns not to use it at a pressure greater than 45mbar in any circumstance and that a pressure regulator should be used in that case. I can't find any gas regulators that output a 37mbar pressure. Is it ok if I use it with 28mbar, 29mbar or 30mbar for example? These are the only ones I could find in my country. Are there any risks to do so?

Comment: Is your gas stove set up for using LPG? If it was used in a home with "Natural Gas" piped in, that is very different from LPG and requires different burners, orifices etc. They are ***not*** interchangeable.

Comment: Yes it is. It says so in the manual.

Comment: 37 mbar is about 15 inches of water column (14.9 inH2O) and about 0.54 psi. In the US the standard natural gas regulators on residential gas meters regulate the pressure to 7 inches of water column (17 mbar or 0.25 psi). You could try to get the closest one to 37 mbar and try it. Could you contact the mfgr?

Comment: Wow that is high pressure, on this side of the pond we limit the pressure to less than 2-3 psi inside a structure for commercial and less than 1 psi for residential.  Here I have installed units that can use both gasses but a difference orifice on the output of the regulator was required larger for lpg than natural gas but other than that the burners were the same never that high of a pressure even in a 500k Btu flash furnace did not exceede these pressures.

Comment: A orifice change may be all that is needed. I have done this on my own home for ovens and bbq’s. From memory a larger size is needed for lpg compared to natural gas.

Comment: @Ed Beal I don't understand your characterization of this as high pressure based on your statement that in the US we limit the indoor pressure to less than 1 psi. Unless I have made a mistake in conversion 37 mbar is 0.54 psi. This is about twice what we normally use inside residences in the US, but is much less than 1 psi.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. Commercial systems I have worked on were under 3 psi and up to 3/4 psi in residential so we agree on that.

Comment: My concern isn't whether or not it would work, but wether or not there would be any risk to use a different pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and make sure you don't exceed 37mbar. The only setback is that the heat output will be lower resulting to longer cooking time.

Answer (score -1):

I just saw this again 15 “ of WC .43 psi per inch if memory serves is +6psi, but as I said a difference in orifice size has all that has been needed in many cases of bbq’s , water heaters and standard household ovens on this side Of the pond work on ~3/4 psi and commercial at 2 psi.
My wife recently purchased a commercial stove / oven for our home, we did need to change the regulator and oven jets in this model that was designed for NG to run on LPG It is awesome but most folks don’t want to pay over 6k for a fancy setup like this. And it has the exact same burners on the stove top and ovens it can be done in many cases in my experience.